Api Node Js não salva dados no BD MySql com o JSON no modelo 1 : N
Estou tentando salvar dados de Customers e Address via Node JS e o problema é que apenas os dados de Customers são gravados. 
Vi vários exemplos na internet e todos os exemplos de CRUD demonstram apenas uma tabela como exemplo de insert. 
Obs. estou usando node js, express - npm e sequelize - npm
{
  "cnpjParameter": "12312312312312",
  "nameBusiness": "INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO DE EMBALAGENS LTDA.",
  "address": {
    "ufParameter": "SP",
    "logradouro": "AV MARIO HABERFELD",
    "numero": "555"
  }
}



Veja https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
